# Does Mahabhagavata Purana mention Hanuman as Shiva amsha?

Tags: shiva, bhagavata-purana, hanuman

I have seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman) article on Wikipedia which tells that Hanuman is Shiva amsha and refers to Mahabhagavatha Purana. Is it mentioned in Mahabhagavatam as such?

Comment: Shiva Purana mentions Hanuman as Avatar of Shiva aka Shankara.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Can you please point to the verse in Shiva Purana

Comment: Do you want reference as answer only from Bagavatam or any purana?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm mainly looking from Bagavatam